# Variáveis estourando

Tags: c

As variaveis `cont_setosa`, `cont_versicolor`, `cont_virginica` estao estourando no final do código, por que?? Como arrumar isso?

Antes dos IFs as variáveis estão normais, porem depois deles, ha essa alteração...

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element{
    int index;
    long double dist;
}Element;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *classe_aux, classe_main;
    classe_aux = &classe_main;

    int k = 3;
    int i = 0;
    Element el[3] = {{1},
                     {1},
                     {1}};

    int cont_setosa = 0;
    int cont_versicolor = 0;
    int cont_virginica = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (el[i].index == 0)
        {
            cont_setosa++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (el[i].index == 1)
            {
                cont_versicolor++;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( el[i].index == 2)
                {
                    cont_virginica++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%i %i %i\n", cont_setosa, cont_versicolor, cont_virginica);

    if ( cont_setosa > cont_versicolor && cont_setosa > cont_virginica)
    {
        strcpy(classe_aux, "Iris-setosa");
    }
    else
    {
        if ( cont_versicolor > cont_setosa && cont_versicolor > cont_virginica)
        {
            strcpy(classe_aux, "Iris-versicolor");
        }
        if ( cont_virginica > cont_setosa && cont_virginica > cont_versicolor)
        {
            strcpy(classe_aux,"Iris-virginica");
        }
    } 

    printf("%i %i %i\n", cont_setosa, cont_versicolor, cont_virginica);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Saida:

```
0 3 0
1936876918 1819239273 29295
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir essa situação com o seu código de exemplo, precisa efetuar alguma modificação?

Comment: Não, é so rodar normalmente, não tem nem entrada o codigo, testei ele em dois compiladores no computador e um online e sempre se mantem estourando as variáveis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você está corrompendo a memória da pilha/stack.

A variável `classe_aux` é um ponteiro que aponta para `classe_main`.

`classe_main` por sua vez é uma variável do tipo `char`, ela armazena apenas um caractere, então quando você faz `strcpy(classe_aux, "Iris-setosa")` por exemplo, você está alocando o primeiro caractere 'I' no `classe_main`, e os outros caracteres são alocados logo em seguida, na região do stack, em posições que outras variáveis estão utilizando, corrompendo sua memória.

Se você declarar a variável `classe_aux` como um array de tamanho 16 por exemplo, isso já resolveria o problema de memória nesse caso.

[Link](https://ideone.com/2zPhHZ) com o código funcionando.